# Angular unit testing "If part not taken"

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

```
 Dname = JSON.stringify(this.userDetails);
  Dpass = JSON.stringify({
    userName: 'test',
    password: 'test'
  });

  onSubmit() {
    this.userDetails = this.inputForm.value;
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.Dname === this.Dpass) {
      this.router.navigate(['/page1']);
      console.log('ok');
    } else {
      console.log('not ok');
    }
  }
```

[**If path not taken --can someone help me to solve this issue in angular unit testing**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppMVX.png)

Comment: instead of a pic, why not copy and paste the code?

Comment: It's very hard to work with image - please, paste the code

Comment: i had shared screenshot of the code

Comment: Hi Tony, welcome to stackoverflow. Don't be discouraged, a lot of new contributors post images of code, but it's an easy mistake to fix. Make sure to post text for all future questions

Comment: What does "if part not taken" even mean?

Comment: Hi byxor ..sorry i am very new to this.. thanks for your guidance.. i had uploaded my code snippet now..thanks everyone in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can spyOn `navigate` function of `this.router` and check using [toHaveBeenCalledWith](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies)

Answer (score 0):

you should set them equal in the beforeEach testBed.configureTestingModule:

```
.then(() => {
     fixture = TestBed.createComponent(YourComponent);
     component = fixture.componentInstance;
     component.Dname = component.Dpass
});
```

The values will evaluate to true and you can take that path by using spyOn for this method and hitting it with a .callThrough. Here's an example:

```
it('should execute methodName', () => {
        const spy = spyOn(component, 'methodName').and.callThrough();
        component.methodName();
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
 });
```